# Generate testing data with PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, scripting

I need to fill a partitioned table with 100 000 of records generated by PL/SQL.
I am thinking about creating a procedure with a loop that will iterate 100000 times. To generate the strings I want to use bind variables and dbms_random.
I am not familiar with PL/SQL developing, so I doubt if it is a good practice.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use PL/SQL?

Comment: This a condition of an examination task.

Comment: So you have an examination task that requires you to use PL/SQL but you are not familiar with it. I think if I was answering a exam question about C# I would try to become more familiar with C# before even attempting it.

Comment: @BriteSponge it is obvious. :) I am on the way. I don't asking to provide the code, just want to clarify if is a good solution or not

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Then I would suggest that using PL/SQL may well be less efficient depending on the exact requirements of your test data. If your requirements mean you MUST use PL/SQL then consider using bulk operations.

Comment: @BriteSponge thanks, for the suggestion. After brief researching, I've figured out that the bulk operations can greatly improve performance while fetching a lot of rows. But for now, I don't how it can help with generating a lot of rows. So, I'll keep learning plsql. 
If there are more any good advices I'd be happy to get them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally found [this](https://www.oraclerecipes.com/sql/creating-a-dummy-table-for-tests/) solution
I am wondering how easy and simple it is.